# Retrieving specific properties from value of ObjectResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, azure, asp.net-core

I am calling a HTTP endpoint which returns the follow below as an `ObjectResult` (variable name = Food):

```
{
"fruit": "apple",
"vegetable": "carrot",
"meat": "steak"
}
```

Within `Food`, of type `ObjectResult`, how do I return the value of... let's say `fruit`?

I would like the output to be `"fruit": "apple"`

It looks like these values are within `Food.Value`. However, I can't pick specific properties (Fruit) from them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please show us the code

Answer (score 0):

> Within Food, of type ObjectResult, how do I return the value of... let's say fruit?

If you'd like to get data from an ObjectResult, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
var objresult = new ObjectResult(Food);

dynamic data = objresult.Value;
var fruit = data.fruit;
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to return it or change it to a "jsonResult" type?

Comment: Also, I seem to be getting an error: Exception while executing function - anonymously hosted dynamicmethods assembly. Function does not contain a definition for fruit